# How does controller interact with view or model in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to RoR, so i don't understand the internal mechanism of interaction between view and controller.
In any controller we can see the code like that:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
end
```

How does ruby interpreter knows where to get ApplicationController class without any `'require'` statment.
Also, how does our controller knows about all models. I mean we if we have product model we can use in our controller the code like:

```
Product.find(1);
```

But how actually controller know about the model class

Comment: You're asking questions that would really better be answered by reading a good book on the subject, I would suggest you start [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ruby-on-rails/info).

Comment: [This RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/395-action-controller-walkthrough) will shed some light...

Comment: i am already reading "Agile web development with rails" but it doesn't give me answers. this book just provide me with excellent tutorial how to make shop. I can craft simple apps but internal mechanism i have not understood yet.

Comment: the $LOAD_PATH usually isn't dealt with in basic tutorials. I like this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For models, open a rails console in your app and type:

> $LOAD_PATH

you will see that the models class is pretty early. This is how auto_loading in Rails is handled.

For views, there is a views_paths which can be manipulated and is outlined here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/ViewPaths/ClassMethods.html